# Не удается подключиться к БД "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь подключиться к бд. Хост, пользователь, пароль - встают нормально. Но при поыытке выбора определенной бд появляется ошибка " Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Отрывок кода:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'login', 'password');

if($connection == false)
{
    echo '$connection = Нет; ';
    exit();
} else
{
    echo '$connection = Да; ';
}

$db=mysql_select_db('users');
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
if (!$connection || !$db)
{
exit(mysql_error());
} 
?>
```

На выходе: $connection = Да; $db = Нет; Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db=mysqli_select_db('users'); // у вас $db=mysql_select_db('users');
mysqli_set_charset("utf8");    // у вас mysql_set_charset("utf8");
....
exit(mysqli_error());          // у вас  exit(mysql_error());
```

Comment: С первой попытки не понял, что у вас за `/*i*/` :Р

Comment: @Visman баг фиксед =)